# How to set all elements of one column of dataframe to arrays?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I just want to know how to set all elements of one column of dataframe to arrays in Pandas.

Just like this, column one and two

```
  a b c d   one    two
0 1 2 3 4 [1, 2] [1, 2]
1 2 2 3 4 [2, 2] [2, 2]
2 3 2 3 4 [3, 2] [3, 2]
```

I have tried, but only in this way:

```
d['one']=[[1,2],[2,2],[3,2]]
```

And if I want to use the numpy array instead of python built-in array, like:

```
d['one']=np.array([[1,2],[2,2],[3,2]])
```

It comes to:

```
  a b c d one  two
0 1 2 3 4  1 [1, 2]
1 2 2 3 4  2 [2, 2]
2 3 2 3 4  3 [3, 2]
```

Or I want to set a column to one same array at one time, for example,

```
d['one']=[1,2], or d['c']=[1,2]
```

Like this:

```
  a b c d   one    two
0 1 2 3 4 [1, 2] [1, 2]
1 2 2 3 4 [1, 2] [2, 2]
2 3 2 3 4 [1, 2] [3, 2]
```

It has error:

*ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index*

Also, If I want to change the values of column b to arrays according to conditions, I found I can't do this. Because I need to use conditions, so there exists a sequence of the assignment operations, which means I can't set the column to arrays like this:

```
d['b']=[[1,2],[6,7],[6,7]]
```

, at one time. I need to do it step by step.

For example, set the column b to [1,2] where a=1 firstly,

```
d.loc[d['a']==1,'b']=[1,2]
  a     b c d   one    two
0 1 [1,2] 3 4 [1, 2] [1, 2]
1 2     2 3 4 [2, 2] [2, 2]
2 3     2 3 4 [3, 2] [3, 2]
```

Then set the column b to [6,7],[6,7] where a=2 or a=3,

```
d.loc[(d['a']==2)|(d['a']==3),'b']=[6,7]
  a    b  c d   one    two
0 1 [1,2] 3 4 [1, 2] [1, 2]
1 2 [6,7] 3 4 [2, 2] [2, 2]
2 3 [6,7] 3 4 [3, 2] [3, 2]
```

The former one has error:

*Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable*

If I do it in another way:

```
d['b'][0]=[1,2]
```

Also error:

*ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.*

And the latter one comes to:

```
  a b c d   one    two
0 1 2 3 4 [1, 2] [1, 2]
1 2 6 3 4 [2, 2] [2, 2]
2 3 7 3 4 [3, 2] [3, 2]
```

, which is not I want, so how to write to achieve this effect?

To sum up,

1. How can I use numpy array to achieve this? How can I set a column to one same array at one time?
2. How can I change the values of a column to arrays according to conditions?

Comment: Normally cells of a DataFrame (Series) hold numbers and strings.  Putting lists or arrays there works, but can create problems.  For example the `csv` save will save the `str(..)` representation of those elements, making it hard to reload the file.

Comment: Double check this, but I suspect that when you try to put a list or other sequence in a Series cell, it turns that Series into Object dtype.  Individual list can put in such an object,  Maybe whole arrays.  Based on experience with object dtype arrays, I'm not surprised that you have problems trying to distribute a 2d array across the cells of a Series.

Answer (score 0):

**Reproducing your example:**

Considering the dataframe:

```
>> d = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3],
>>                   'b': [2, 2, 2],
>>                   'c': [3, 3, 3],
>>                   'd': [4, 4, 4]})
```

The code as you tested generate a list of lists, and the dataframe interpret as each list as a value for a row:

```
>> d['one']=[[1,2],[2,2],[3,2]]
>> print(d['one'][0])
>> print(type(d['one'][0]))
[1, 2]
<class 'list'>
```

**Now, storing the numpy.array into the dataframe:**

If you build a list of arrays, you will be able to store it as you want:

```
>> two = [np.array([1,2]), np.array([2,2]),np.array([3,2])]
>> d['two']= two
>> print(d['two'][0])
>> print(type(d['two'][0]))
[1 2]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

To facilitate this operation, you could use a lambda/apply function:

```
>> d['three'] = [[1,2],[2,2],[3,2]]
>> d['three'] = d['three'].apply(lambda x: tuple(x)).apply(np.array)
>> print(d['three'][0])
>> print(type(d['three'][0]))
[1 2]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

**To get data as you described**

To check if the first `value == 3` or the column `three` of an array matches the condition, also using lambda/apply:

```
d[d.apply(lambda x: x['three'][0] == 3, axis=1)]
    a   b   c   d   one two three
2   3   2   3   4   [3, 2]  [3, 2]  [3, 2]
```